# Cygwin dies waiting for dll to load

Tags: cygwin

When using cygwin I often get some error followed by a stack trace that looks like

```
123456789 [main] ssh 1234 fork: child 4321 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
```

I get this very often when using git-svn, and have also heard of people getting this error using apache httpd, xist, gvim. I haven't ever been able to track down the root cause of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curing the symptom of this problem took some googling.

1. Shutdown cygserver (if running): `net stop cygserver`
2. Close all cygwin processes
3. Run the ash shell `C:\path\to\cygwin\bin\ash.exe`
4. Run rebaseall `$./rebaseall`

This should get things working again.

This is based on http://www.garethhunt.com/2008/02/11/cygwin-died-waiting-for-dll-loading/